# C array of struct pointers - assigning new values

Tags: c

What am I missing? I'm a beginner in C, but still the result I get is unexpected for me. I simplified the case to get only the error.

```
struct str {
    int a;
};
struct str* strArray[100];


int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        struct str str1;
        str1.a=i;
        strArray[i]=&str1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        printf("i:\t%d\n",strArray[i]->a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result printed is a hundred 99s. What I would expect is: 1, 2, 3 ...

Comment: Heard of scope? Things disappear when they go out of scope

Comment: I see ... Sorry, I'm used to programming in Java, things behave differently there ...

Comment: @neuromouse if you are programming in a different language, you shouldn't expect the same behavior.

Comment: " What I would expect is: 1, 2, 3 ..." -- Really? Where is the memory where all those different values reside? You have defined only one `struct str`, namely `str1`. `strArray` only contains *pointers*, and they all point to `str1`. In fact, your program has undefined behavior because you're accessing `str1` outside its scope, so the program could print anything at all (or nothing).

Comment: " I'm a beginner in C, but still the result I get is unexpected for me." -- That's an odd way to put it. Results are **often** unexpected by beginners. It would make far more sense if someone said "I'm an old hand at C, but still the result I get is unexpected for me".

Comment: " Sorry, I'm used to programming in Java, things behave differently there ..." -- Not really. In Java, you would have to say `Str str1 = new Str()`. In C, you could do something similar with `struct str* str1 = malloc(sizeof *str1)`. What you are doing -- allocating `str1` on the stack and then taking its address with `&` -- has no correspondence in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This declaration inside the loop

```
struct str str1;
```

produces a variable of type `struct str` that is valid only for the duration of the iteration of the loop in which it has been created. Once the iteration is over, `str1` becomes invalid. If you decide to access it by pointer outside the scope of that iteration, you get *undefined behavior*.

You can use `malloc` to make "durable" `struct`s for use later in the program:

```
strArray[i]= malloc(sizeof(struct str));
strArray[i]->a = i;
```

Since your `struct`s are allocated dynamically, you need to free them once you are done using `strArray` elements:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    free(strArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whole strArray is pointing to str1 which contains 99 at last so  your whole array locations pointing to 99 which str1 contains at last of first loop iteration.

Comment: The value of `str1.a` is undefined after the first loop completes (in fact, after each iteration of that loop completes) ... it need not be 99.